# Combining records from two sorted files

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have two big files with more than six million records. Data in those two files can be correlated by [UID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_identifier) (if ordering the file, should be at same row in both files). Eventually I need to get data from the first file concatenated with data in the second file.

The issue is that executing the script is taking 10 hours for about 650,000 records!!

I'd like to improve it.

```
UIDS=`cut -f1 -d',' sorted_UID_data1.txt`

for record in $UIDS
do
    echo `grep $record sorted_UID_data1.txt| awk -F ',' '{print $2}'`,`grep $record sorted_UID_data2.txt` >> data.txt
done
```

In order to optimize it, I thought of

```
TOTAL_RECORDS=`wc -l < sorted_UID_data1.txt`

recordId=1
while [ $recordId -le $TOTAL_RECORDS ]
do
    echo `sed -n "${recordId}{p;q;}" sorted_UID_data1.txt| awk -F ',' '{print $2}'`,`sed -n "${recordId}{p;q;}" sorted_UID_data2.txt` >> data.txt
    recordId=$(( $recordId + 1 ))
done
```

And this is also taking too much time.

But then, I'm thinking: What if I always can grab the first line of the file? I've seen that this could be done by [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed), [tail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_%28Unix%29), or [AWK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK), but this seems to be inefficient.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Cross posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32806513/removing-1st-line-of-a-text-file

Comment: Both of your attempts read the *whole* file once (or twice!) for *each* record, so they're O(n^2).  If you'd needed to do something more complicated than `join` or `paste` could handle, you could read all the lines of one file into an associative array in awk, or a list or hash in perl, then process the other file and grab appropriate entries from the first file.  If they're both sorted, `perl` is a good choice for reading from two files at once.  I think awk makes that fairly easy, too, but you'd have to process it with `split` manually, not awk field splitting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To remove the first line use `tail` :

```
# seq 5 | tail -n +2
2
3
4
5
```

And to only "grab the first line" use `head` :

```
# seq 5 | head -n 1
1
```

But to join two files line by line use `paste` :

```
# seq 5 > nums
# echo -e 'a\nb\nc\nd\ne' > chars
# paste nums chars     
1       a
2       b
3       c
4       d
5       e
```

And to join two files with matching common fileds use `join`:

```
# paste -d , <( seq 5 ) <( seq 11 15 ) > teens
# paste -d , <( seq 5 ) <( seq 21 25 ) > twenties
# join -t , teens twenties
1,11,21
2,12,22
3,13,23
4,14,24
5,15,25
```

Comment: this is still inefficient if there is a need to do it on 6M records

Comment: Then, use `paste` to begin with. The `tail` and `head`  examples were there to answer the question in the topic.

Answer (score 4):

As you use key-field better use **join**

```
join -t ',' sorted_UID_data1.txt sorted_UID_data2.txt
```

Comment: assuming the files are sorted (an the common field used as a key)  beforehand.

Comment: @MichelBillaud Did you see **sorted_UID**_data1.txt?

Comment: Yes, of course. Well,  the first message says : <<   Data in those 2 files can be correlated by UID (if ordering the file, should be at same row in both files). >>. The "if ordering" somehow weakens  the belief  that they are actually ordered.
So, better safe than sorry, insisting on this point may not hurt.

Comment: There are several other points in the message that are not clear: 1) why the title "removing 1st line from a text file" 2) concatenation of the files, where the deal is about pasting the lines.  So this make me feel the terminology used in the question has to be swallowed with caution and a grain of salt.